HP Z8 G4 with an Nvidia 980 GPU and AMD's amdkmpfd.sys driver unable to remove the driver
So, I have a HP Z8 G4 with an Nvidia card, running Windows 11. This computer has never had an AMD card installed, but I do have the amdkmpfd.sys driver installed. I tried removing it manually via regedit, but after rebooting the system won't recognize the Nvidia GPU, tried to reinstall the drivers, the installer says I don't have an Nvidia GPU. I reinstalled the amdkmpfd.sys drivers, and everything works fine. Tried using DDU in Safe Mode to remove all GPU drivers (marked amdkmpfd.sys for removal), it claimed it was successful but the AMD driver is still there.
What am I missing? Does the HP Z8 G4 have some sort of AMD PCI bus while using an Intel Xeon CPU? I can't seem to figure it out.

If your nvidia card does not work when you uninstall amdkmpfd.sys then you do not have a nvidia gpu. “Does the HP Z8 G4 have some sort of AMD PCI bus while using an Intel Xeon CPU?” - No, this absolutely isn’t the case

You probably have a 1x AMD Radeon™ Pro W6800 GPUs instead of the Nvidia A6000 option.

I have removed the Quadro GPU it came with, and manually installed a Sapphire GTX 980. So assuming I have another GPU is not being very helpful.
